# How to get a colored tab completion?

Tags: bash

Is there a way to get colored output when using tab completion in a terminal?  My colors are fine everywhere else so I know that I've enabled a color terminal successfully.

Using bash in Ubuntu (10.10).

Comment: How do you specify a "colored output when using tab completion"?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's no facility within Bash to color output during completion as there is in fish and zsh. One could write completion functions that output color control sequences, but you'd have to maintain copies of the proposed completions with and without color codes or strip the out when the user makes a selection since Bash uses the selection directly normally and the color codes would get in the way.

If this is an important feature for you, I would recommend that you consider using zsh.

**Update**

Bash 4.3 readline adds a variable that enables color for tab completion to show different colors for executable files, directories, etc., during tab completion:

```
colored-stats
```

Readline in the upcoming Bash 4.4 adds a variable which enables color to indicate the matching portion of the string during tab completion.

```
colored-completion-prefix
```

You can see the values of these variables using

```
bind -v | grep color
```

To set them, add lines(s) to your `~/.inputrc` file such as:

```
set colored-stats on
```

Comment: I'll look into zsh, but at this point I fear I am too lazy to switch to a different shell :)

Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Ryan: Zsh is quite compatible with Bash. You would probably find the switch to be fairly easy. It has a lot of powerful features that Bash doesn't have (or you have to use external utilities for). There are only a few things that are significantly different in the basics. An example is that array indexes are one-based instead of zero-based, but there's a setting that affects that. I only use zsh occasionally, though.

Comment: Is there a way to change the default colours?  E.g. the completion options for man pages are blinking (on a red background, like broken symlinks on my system), which makes them invisible half of the time and hard to scan by eye.

Comment: @AstroFloyd: From the [Bash Manua](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Init-File-Syntax): "The color definitions are taken from the value of the `LS_COLORS` environment variable." The documentation for that variable is [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/dir_colors.5.html). There isn't a setting for `man` pages, so you'll need to look at where your `LS_COLORS` gets set and find the color combination that corresponds and change it. On my system, `man` page names don't get colored when being tab completed (and broken symlinks, while red-on-gray in `ls` output, ...

Comment: ... are light-blue like valid symlinks during tab-completion).

Comment: Not working for me on MacOS Mojave 10.14.4. My Bash --version is `version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0)`

Comment: @AndyCarlson: Does `bind -v | grep color` show both `set colored-completion-prefix on` and `set colored-stats on`? If so, what happens when you type the letter a followed by pressing tab twice? If you've added the settings to your `~/.inputrc` but haven't started a new terminal or haven't executed `re-read-init-file` by pressing control-x control-r then the settings won't have taken effect.

Comment: I had started a new terminal session. No luck. `bind -v` outputs neither option :( 
I even tried setting those options again in my prompt. Still nothing. It's totally ignoring it.

Comment: Interestingly, I do get colored tab completion in the Python REPL, which I know to be using Readline 8 thanks to Homebrew.

Comment: @AndyCarlson What is output at a bash prompt when you press ctrl-x ctrl-v?

Comment: Whoa! It output a different version than what `bash --version` did. Instead it output `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)`

Comment: I figured it out! The version I *thought* I was using was not in fact my default shell. There was another installed by Brew. When running `bash --version` it was showing me the wrong version. I simply had to add the new version's path (`/usr/local/bin/bash`) into the `/etc/shells` file and run `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash`. Thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: @AndyCarlson That's likely the default installation of Bash in MacoOS. They've stuck it at 3.2 because they don't like the change in licensing. If you enter `type -a bash` it should show you each place that Bash is present in your `PATH`. The first one takes precedence if you just enter `bash`. If you run them directly you'll get each particular version: `/bin/bash --version` outputs 3.2.57, `/Users/dennis/homebrew/bin/bash --version` outputs 4.4.12 for me.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know about completion colors for command options and arguments but for filename and directories, according to (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/133866) user495470 states that in Bash 4.3 and later you can add `set colored-stats on` to `~/.inputrc` to get colored completion when you do `ls <tab>`.